# How to decide the type of the variable inside Constructors in java?

Tags: java, types, scope

I have created a Matrix class in Java that works for both int and float. For this I found that it would be very convenient for me if I would be able to declare variable mat as int or float depending on the parameters passed by the user to the constructors.

My Current approach is:

```
package Matrix;
public class Matrix
{
    int row,col,mat[][];
    float fmat[][];
    boolean real=false;
    public Matrix(int r,int c)
    {
        row=r;
        col=c;
        mat=new int[r][c];
    }
    public int determinant()
    {
        //Code to calculate and return Determinant of mat
    }
}
```

I just want to get rid of fmat and mat should accessible to other methods like determinant. I know that I can store both int and float in a float type array, but due to some reasons I don't want this. I can also make the type as Number or Object but methods of Integer or Float class won't work on those. If there is a solution, please let me know. Any alternative solutions are also welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like `Matrix` should be generic.

Comment: Like @djechlin said: use Generics, you can find a tutorial here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html

Comment: @Marged I still UVed this because I'm not sure how to add and multiply generics in Java (i.e. enforce they're Integer or Float), and I'm not sure how to route the code differently based on function arguments being int or float.

Answer (score 2):

As other users have pointed out, me too, I recommend to you to refactorize your abstraction to a *generic* one with one numeric parameter which represents the type of the contained elements:

```
public class Matrix<T extends Number>
{
    private int rows;
    private int cols;
    private T[][] elements;

    public T determinant()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Through this form, the compiler will make sure that any type set in place of parameter `T` will be a subclass of `Number`. You may use the parametrized type `T` all along the definition of Matrix.

When you have implemented your class, you can use like this:

```
Matrix<Integer> matrixOfIntegers=new Matrix<Integer>(10, 20);
int determinant1=matrixOfIntegers.determinant();

Matrix<Double> matrixOfDoubles=new Matrix<Double>(10, 20);
double determinant2=matrixOfDoubles.determinant();
```

Comment: Not really essential to your main point, but determinant of an integer matrix will still be a double but any usual sense of the words.

Comment: You're right, but I've adapted my example to the OP, in which the determinant returns an `int`. Anyway, that's a design decission.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something using generics to accomplish this, as suggested by @addigo.  If your application has performance requirements, I personally recommend against this and would either do what you're doing or write two separate classes.  It might be that you won't take a performance hit from using generics, but my starting position would be concern that the compiler will not optimize the calculation well through the auto-unboxing that is likely to result (or if you do it, the explicit unboxing).

To elaborate, if you use generics, the most direct way would be do declare this:

```
 public class Matrix<T extends Number> {
    private T[][] mat;

    // Rest of class
 }
```

This in itself isn't bad.  But then you're going to get to something like an "add" method as a simple example.  That's going to look like this

```
 public Matrix<T> add(Matrix<T> m) {
    // Check for consistency of matrix dimensions
    T[][] sum = new double[getRowDim()][getColDim()];
    for(int i = 0; i < getRowDim(); ++i) {
         for(int j = 0; j < getColDim(); ++j) {
             sum[i][j] = mat[i][j] + m.mat[i][j]; // Auto unboxing happens here
         }
     }
     return new Matrix(sum);
  }
```

I've made some assumptions about other methods here that I'm not defining explicitly but whose meaning should be obvious. (There are also some other optimizations that I'm skipping for clarity and brevity.)

You'll also have some issues properly handling the case where you want to, say, add an object of type `Matrix<Float>` with an object of type `Matrix<Integer>`.  These are not insurmountable, but I think they will start to defeat the benefits that you got from using generics in the first place.

Just my opinion, of course.  If you don't care about speed or your confident that the compiler is good enough to eliminate the issue, the generics could still be a good option.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Generic ? 
like:
Matrix, and declare mat as: T[][] mat

Comment: As you have already taken the time to phrase an answer: why not give him an example based on his original code ?